# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: start for class: WorkflowScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Groovy/Jenkins and am building a Jenkins pipeline. It was working fine until I tried fixing a loop built into the script. Below is the code before the change:

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    choice name: 'TargetEnvironment', description: '<b>Mandatory</b>: environment against which to book trades and roll the date.', choices: getChoices("${JENKINS_ENV_CHOICES_PATH}")
    string name: 'NumberOfDaysToRoll', trim: true, defaultValue: '', description: '<i>Mandatory</i>: The total number of days you wish to roll the dates and book trades.'
    booleanParam name: 'RunPaymentWindow', description: '<i>Optional</i>: Select to run payment window following final date roll.', defaultValue: false
    string name: 'Email', trim: true, defaultValue: '', description: '<i>Optional</i>: e-mail(s) to notify upon completion.<br>Several e-mails can be set with semi-colon ; separation.'
}
options {
    buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '5', numToKeepStr: '')
}
environment {
    GENERATE_MESSAGES_FULL_PATH = "${env.GENERATED_MESSAGES_DIRECTORY}/${env.GENERATED_MESSAGES_ARCHIVE_NAME}"
}
stages {
    stage('Set-up') {
        steps {
            //Checking mandatory parameters
            script {
                if (params.TargetEnvironment.isEmpty()) {
                    error 'You must set an Environment'
                }
                if (params.NumberOfDaysToRoll.isEmpty()) {
                    error 'You must set a number of days to rollover the date'
                }
                currentBuild.displayName = params.TargetEnvironment
                //REMOVE BELOW LINE WHEN RUNNING PIPELINE FROM GIT
                git branch: 'MUREX-15906', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'fb4d5781-fa37-40e5-8dd1-ceff1ae7058d', poll: false, url: 'git@github.aus.thenational.com:Murex/mx-automation.git'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Trade inserts and date rollover') {
        steps {
            script {
                for (int i = 1; i <=params.NumberOfDaysToRoll; i++) {
                    String mxName = params.TargetEnvironment.replaceFirst("mx", "").toUpperCase();
                    env.QueueManager = 'devtest';
                    env.QueuesSuffix = mxName;
                    if (mxName.equals("T00")) {
                        env.QueueManager = 'sit';
                        env.QueuesSuffix = ' ';
                    } else if (mxName.equals("STG")) {
                        env.QueueManager = 'stg'
                        env.QueuesSuffix = ' ';
                    } else if (mxName.startsWith("AS") || mxName.startsWith("PC") || mxName.startsWith("UAT")) {
                        env.QueueManager = 'stg'
                        env.QueuesSuffix = mxName;
                    }
                    String getDateOutput = env.WORKSPACE + "/get_date_output.txt"
                    String scriptPath = env.WORKSPACE + "/scripts/get_global_fo_desk_date.sh"
                    String scriptExec = scriptPath + " " + getDateOutput
                    sh "chmod 777 " + env.WORKSPACE
                    sh "chmod 755 " + env.WORKSPACE + "/scripts"
                    sh "chmod 755 " + scriptPath
                    echo "[INFO] Retrieving generation date from [" + params.TargetEnvironment + "] via [" + scriptExec + "]"
                    build job: 'execute_remote_script',
                        parameters: [string(name: 'MX_ENV', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                                    string(name: 'SCRIPT_PATH', value: scriptExec)]
                    env.environmentDate = sh returnStdout: true, script: "cat " + getDateOutput
                    env.environmentDate = env.environmentDate.trim()
                    sh "chmod 755 " + env.WORKSPACE
                    env.interfaceDate = sh returnStdout: true, script: "date -d " + env.environmentDate + " +%Y-%m-%d"
                    env.interfaceDate = env.interfaceDate.trim()
                    if (env.interfaceDate.isEmpty()) {
                        error 'Failed to retrieve environment date for interface'
                    } else {
                        echo "[INFO] Environment date for interface found as [" + env.interfaceDate + "]"
                    }
                    echo "[INFO] Turning on queue-transfer"
                    build job: 'queue-transfer-start-stop',
                    parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                            string(name: 'Action', value: start),
                            string(name: 'Email', value: params.Email)]
                    echo "[INFO] Restarting workflows"
                    sh "$MX_APP/mxmlexchange/xmlrequestscript_launchsheets.sh"
                    //echo "[INFO] Beginning trade insertions"
                    //build job: 'atum',
                    //parameters: [string(name: 'QueueManager', value: env.QueueManager),
                    //      string(name: 'QueuesSuffix', value: env.QueuesSuffix),
                    //      string(name: 'MessagesPath', value: '/export/mx/murex_share/stats/prod_incoming_messages/data/' + env.interfaceDate + '-mxpc-incoming_messages-masked.tgz'),
                    //      string(name: 'Environment', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                    //      string(name: 'ExcludeInterface', value: ' '),
                    //      string(name: 'Email', value: params.Email)]
                    sh "chmod 755 " + env.WORKSPACE + "/scripts/date_roll.sh"
                    echo "[INFO] Rolling date"
                    build job: 'execute_remote_script',
                                parameters: [string(name: 'MX_ENV', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                                            string(name: 'SCRIPT_PATH', value: env.WORKSPACE + "/scripts/date_roll.sh")]
                }

            }

        }
    }
    stage('Run payment window (optional)') {
        steps {
            script {
                if (params.RunPaymentWindow) {
                    build job: 'execute_remote_script',
                                parameters: [string(name: 'MX_ENV', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                                            string(name: 'SCRIPT_PATH', value: ". ~/nab_env.ksh; $MX_CUSTOMER_BIN/mx_run_ps.ksh \"PC_SET_FIX_WIN\" \"PC_PROC\"")]

                }
            }
        }
    }

}

post {
    always {
        script {
            if (! params.Email.isEmpty()) {
                mail to: params.Email,
                    subject: "Pipeline [${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}] [${currentBuild.currentResult}]",
                    body: "URL: ${currentBuild.absoluteUrl}\nParameters: {$params}\nRan on : ${env.NODE_NAME}"
            }
        }
        //deleteDir()
    }
}
}
  def getChoices(path) {
    def choices = []
    String file = new File(path).text
    def content = file.split("\n")

    for(c in content) {
        choices.add(c)
    }
    return choices
}
```

Now, there was an error in my loop as you can see, because params.NumberOfDaysToRoll is a string. So to fix this I did the following change to the loop:

```
    stage('Trade inserts and date rollover') {
        steps {
            script {
                def executionLoops = params.NumberOfDaysToRoll.toInteger()
                echo "Execution loops defined as: " + executionLoops
                for (int i = 1; i <=executionLoops; i++) {
                    ...
```

Following this change, I got the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: start for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:354)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:291)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:295)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:74)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Even if I comment out the area of error, as follows, I just get another error for something else:

```
  build job: 'queue-transfer-start-stop',
                    parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: params.TargetEnvironment),
                            string(name: 'Action', value: start),
                            string(name: 'Email', value: params.Email)
```

]

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: you have found error by yourself: `value: start`. `start` is undeclared variable in your script.

Comment: `value: start` should actually be `value: 'start'`, if you just want to pass that as value. Id it is a parameter from elsewhere in your code, it is not declared. Your parameter list has an issue of unknown string being used.